# Basic Protection of a Game Client

Tags: c++, security, design-patterns, dll-injection

I currently have a multiplayer game that players are starting to use memory editing to to cancel attack animation making the attack packets come-in faster or making the attacks a lot faster than normal.

Yes a better design would be ideal but that could take a while. I wanted to get a temporary fix that can be done quick.

The ideas:

- Check time difference between the last attack packet ignore everything that is too fast. (for server)
- Use `EnumWindows` check for window classes and stop the game if a known memory editor is detected. `EnumWindows` will be executed each time an attack is made. (for client)
- Use `ReadProcessMemory` to read running processes and find signitures for known memory editors.

Well the question really is if any of the following could work and how it would be done:

- [Detour](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) `ReadProcessMemory` or `OpenProcess` and exit when called? (though I think this wont work because these functions gets called by the memory editor not my game).
- `ReadProcessMemory` on my self(game) and check the addresses that they are changing. Check if the values are not within the normal range then exit.
- Any suggestions?

I know that it is futile to do this because cheaters that knows what their doing can still get around all this. But my game has only about 600 active players, I believe they are just somewhat `scriptkiddies`. I think this simple countermeasures should be enough for small games like mine. But of course, the design will be corrected.

Comment: `"Check time difference between the last attack packet ignore everything that is too fast. (for server)"` to me this sounds like the easiest and safest by far. If you only have `600` players, you can most likely afford any server overhead. And if it's a server side check, it's unlikely they'll find something that will break the same thing. Why not do this?

Comment: @IVlad yes, this has been implemented. Problem is attacks and skills has different animation delays. There is about 100+ different delays. So the current implementation only checks the shortest delay on all the attacks. Which means they are still able to get the longer delay attacks a bit shorter.

Comment: @IVlad I'm also just checking on other ideas. :)

Comment: Tell the server about all the attack times?

Comment: Delays are somehow written in the client code. Refactor it so that the same values are shared between client and server code. Must control it on the server side. Forget about controlling the client side. That is a wasted time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

> Detour ReadProcessMemory or OpenProcess and exit when called?

These are not being called in your process so hooking them locally wouldn't do anything.  You would need to hook every running process, which is not recommended.

> ReadProcessMemory on my self(game) and check the addresses that they are changing. Check if the values are not within the normal range then exit.

You don't need to ReadProcessMemory, you're inside your own process.  Just check the value normally.

You should calculate these values on the server if you don't want the client's to be able to manipulate them, then just replicate this info to the clients and overwrite them.

You can also add an antidebug library to your client to prevent the majority of people from manipulating your process.  [Here](https://github.com/fengjixuchui/khaleesi) is a decent one